# jQuery autocomplete max limit

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

I want to display autocomplete results,
what is the max limit on the displayed results?

code example:

```
function AutoCompletePositions(){
     j$("#AddPosition").autocomplete({
            source : allPositions
        });
    }
```

"#AddPosition" is the field which get the values from "allPositions" list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no defined max limit option on the displayed results (refer to the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)). However, you can define a custom function to the source parameter where you can [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) on the filtered list:

```
var allPositions = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"];

$("#AddPosition").autocomplete({ 
    source: function(request, response) {
        var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(allPositions, request.term);        
        response(results.slice(0, 10));
    }
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/96kc7bws/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can easily hide the elements with css:

```
<style>
  .ui-widget li:nth-child(n+6) {
      display: none;
  }
</style>
```

This would show only the first 5 choices